# "He Isn't"/"She Isn't" V.S. "He's Not"/"She's Not"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, contractions

Is there a difference in usage between "he isn't"/"she isn't" and "he's not"/"she's not"?

I think "he's not" and "she's not" are stronger because they put more emphasis on the word "not" than "he isn't" and "she isn't" do.

Comment: The one with not can very well be used to emphasize the negative. That is true. But the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. Or no there's not. :)

Isn't is a contraction of "is not".

He's/she's is a contraction of "she is/he is".

They are just different ways of writing the same sentence.

Comment: The one with not ***can be*** more emphatic when spoken.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable and both have the same initial meaning. Similar to "we're not" and "we aren't" because both mean "we are not." The English language is very confusing, in this case, there are multiple ways to say the same phrase.